# using javascript to mark a link as visited

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

FF2 (at least) doesn't mark as link as :visited if it triggers the onclick handler without following the href.  I'm using onclick to fetch data from a server and modify the page and the link styling seems appropriate here.  But the link is not marked as visited.

Is there a cross-browser way to mark the link as visited?  Failing that, is there a way to determine the browser's a:visited styling and apply it to the link?

Thanks to all who replied.

Looks like the **answers** are:

- *Is there a cross-browser way to mark the link as visited?*
  No, there's no way to do this.  Links are identified as visited if the href is in the browser history.

  *Is there a way to determine the browser's a:visited styling?*
  No, not via javascript alone.

Comment: now you can manipulate browser history with javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 29):

Here is how I did it. Only works in [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) that support HTML5 history api.

```
// store the current URL
current_url = window.location.href

// use replaceState to push a new entry into the browser's history
history.replaceState({},"",desired_url)

// use replaceState again to reset the URL
history.replaceState({},"",current_url)
```

Using replaceState means that the back button won't be affected.

Comment: Checked by me in FF 31. Works just great!

Comment: Nathan, is it possible to mark the link as **unvisited**? It will be great improvement over the original userscript that I have: https://pastebin.com/raw/nLnKzy34

Comment: The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise replaceState throws an exception: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

Comment: This still seems to be working in recent Firefoxes and nicely persists across tabs/reloads without affecting back/forward buttons - but I am concerned about the race conditions here. Both `replaceState` & `pushState` seem to change the browser `location`, which you undo by saving & resetting. But that means there's a race condition if other events or threads do stuff - which could cause serious issues with other code, and race conditions are the *worst* to try to debug. Is there a way to add a URL to History to trigger `a:visited` CSS styling in a cleaner, less side-effectful way?

Answer (score 3):

The only *workaround* I know of would be something like the following.

Say, your visited links are red:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someEvent();this.style.color='#ff0000'">link</a>
```

But that doesn't mean that when the page is reloaded, the links are still *marked* visited.

To achieve this, I'd suggest give all links IDs, which are of course unique across your entire app, or namespaced per page. In your `onclick`, you'll trigger another method, which saves the link's ID to a cookie.

The most easiest would be a comma-separated list, which you can `split()` before reading. Which is what you do when the page is reloaded. When it's split, you iterate over all IDs and set the color on your links.

E.g, using jQuery:

```
// onclick
function saveID(id) {
  if ($.cookie('idCookie')) {
    $.cookie('idCookie', $.cookie('idCookie') + "," + id);
  } else {
    $.cookie('idCookie', id);
  }
}

// make all links colored
function setVisted() {
  var idArray = $.cookie('idCookie').split(',');
  for (var x=0; x<idArray.length; x++) {
    $('#' + idArray[x]).css('color', '#ff0000');
  }
}

// assign saveID()
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    saveId($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  setVisited();
});
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should get you started and give you an idea. If you get lucky, it's *paste and win*. ;-) I also haven't researched how much you can store in a cookie and what the performance implications are, or what other restrictions apply, also see my comments.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful for persisting the information.  The part that I don't yet understand (and my browser knowledge is not deep or current) is how to get the styles that the browser wants to apply by default to :visited links.  Back in the misty depths of time, at least, it was possible for users to configure their browser so that visited links appeared in a different color (for example, to deal with colorblindness issues).  Rather than assume the color is red, I'd like to query the style info and apply that to my 'link' elements.  But I don't know how to do that, or even if it's possible.

Comment: Just a comment on my own answer. Maybe even a cookie per page makes sense. But beware of going crazy with this. I'm not sure if the visual achievement is worth it.

Comment: @Doug Just saw your other comment -- you want the browser defaults? I think in Firefox they are "hidden" in about:config. You can probably ready that with an extension, but not from a webpage (thank goodness). ;-)

Comment: For IE, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741310.aspx You can always use the defaults and hope that the user didn't change them. Generally, consistent behaviour of one app is nice. If you adhere to defaults, you'll be save. It won't match a 100% though.

Comment: Wow it works nicely. This is one of high priority requirement for me. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a class that has the same definition as :visited.

Comment: I'm letting the user's browser determine that definition.  The last line of my question asks how to access the definition.

Comment: Yes, sadly, I have a problem with not reading the whole question at times.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as a "visited" state for individual links.  It's the URLs themselves that are interpreted as "visited" by the browser.  Any links that point at a URL in the browser's history will receive styling as defined by the :visited pseudo-style in your CSS.

You could try to fake it by setting the location of a hidden iframe to the desired URL, but that won't force the current page to re-draw so I doubt you'd see the :visited style updates w/o a refresh.

For the 2nd part of your question, I'd probably go with Jordan Jones' answer.

Comment: Hmmm, but I still don't know how to get that information.  Guess I should ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to determine the browser's a:visited styling?

I would say yes since the current document is visited and you can find it's link color like this:-

```
alert(mys_getLinkColor(top.location))


function mys_getLinkColor(href) {
var x, body, res=''
x = document.createElement('a')
x.href = href
body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
body.appendChild(x)
if(x.currentStyle) {
   res = x.currentStyle.color
}
else if(window.getComputedStyle) {
   res = window.getComputedStyle(x,null).color
}
return mys_rgbToHexColor(res) }


function mys_rgbToHexColor(v) { 
// E.g. 'rgb(5,2,11)' converts to "#05020b". All other formats returned unchanged.
var i
v = v.split('(')
if(!v[1]) return v[0]
v = v[1].replace(/ /g, '').replace(/\)/, '')
v = v.split(',')
for(i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
   v[i] = Number(v[i]).toString(16)
   if(v[i].length==1) v[i] = '0' + v[i]
}
return '#'+v.join('')}
```

Comment: Note that you can't do this any more - on the modern, secure browsers at least... This is due to the high profile CSS History Leak vulnerability. For more info on the problem and how it's fixed in FireFox, see http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/