# Is a mailto href ever considered visited?

Tags: html

I styled the `<a>` element as follows

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

In the following using Firefox, Opera, and Chrome

```
<a href="mailto:userid@xyz.edu" >send email</a>
```

All the colors act as expected except that it is never marked as visited.  Is there someway to make it visited?

This is one place IE seems to excel as it does get marked as visited!

Comment: My suspicion is that this is something IE can do due to its coupling with Outlook. Did outlook handle the email message when you clicked the link?

Comment: Also a mailto does not show up in browser history which is where most browsers go to determine whether a link has been visited.

Comment: @ken: All the browsers I tried used my default mailer Firefox.

Comment: Chrome also does not treat the element as visited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mailto is not displayed as visited. I would try jquery to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

It is not considered visited like other people already told you but if you would like to make it look visited, this might help you:
[using javascript to mark a link as visited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795654/using-javascript-to-mark-a-link-as-visited)

Comment: @YK: Can you cite some reference to the effect that standard or common practice is not to mark it as visited?

Answer (score 0):

NO. Visited highlight also work for mailto link on "a" tag. With following conditions..

1. When ever you click on mailto link from any browser on a page, it will trigger your default mail-to browser or application like outlook. I am correct?.
2. So highlight function only work, when your current browser(where you seeing have mailto link page) and default mailto browser are same.
3. For example if you are seeing the page in Mozilla firefox, and mail compose option is opened on firefox then highlight style must be added by browser by default as usual links. Else your compose option opened on chrome or IE or Outlook highlight style not added by browser.

So leave as it is. If you need as compulsory append style when click on link, using JS or JQuery.