# Link's color does not change to visisted when target is blank

Tags: javascript, html

My links doesn't change to default visited color when target is set "_blank". How can I fix it (I want to open link in new window)?
Anybody have experience with it?

Comment: Under Firefox, the visited link color feature has been disabled due to privacy reason. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:visited) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Comment: @Jay, you appear to be mistaken. The summary specifically states, "browsers strictly _limit_ the styles you can apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color, background-color . . ." While they _limit_ what you can change, you _can_ change the color of a :visited link.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your link would change color after you reload the original page, or does it not?

If you are searching for a workaround, that would help you mark link as visited by js, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795654/using-javascript-to-mark-a-link-as-visited) is a thread.

> Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as a "visited" state for
>   individual links. It's the URLs themselves that are interpreted as
>   "visited" by the browser. Any links that point at a URL in the
>   browser's history will receive styling as defined by the :visited
>   pseudo-style in your CSS.

Comment: thank you. No, it does not. I don't want to use js. So can you confirm that browser does not set my link as visited if target is blank?

Comment: no, it should not matter. even if you visited the page without using the link, it should be seen as visited

Comment: could you add an example of a link you are using?

Comment: so strange, my code is really simple: <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"> Google in new window</a>

Comment: does the link work? I tried it and only reason for my browser to not change the color link was if the link was not working. otherwise it worked. the problem is definitely not with target blank. and I had to ad http:// to get the link working.

Comment: Check my answer above, it was posted 1 hour ago with the solution )

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` before `google.com`, otherwise it's a local link. And check your CSS, maybe you used styling like this:

```
a { color: _yourcolor_; }
```

This way it styles all links in all states (including :visited) in one color.