# Make clicked link visited without actually sending the request to server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have requirement to make a clicked link visited (i.e. browser default ":visited" styling can apply to it). However, I do not want the request to be actually sent to server. preventDefault() cannot be used because browser need the click event to happen to add link url to its browsing history for rendering visited links. To make it worse, We need to support IE8, so using HTML5 history api to manually adding url to browser history is not possible either. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: No, there isn't. You either have to use the history api or add a css-class to those links: `a:visited, a.visited { /* Style */ }`.

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795654/using-javascript-to-mark-a-link-as-visited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your HTML as this:

```
   <a href="#" class="visited">Some linke here which by default looks like visited link</a>
```

and your CSS as this:

```
.visited {
    color: #551A8B;
}
```

This would then by default make your link look visited.

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/ygLu3/1/

Hope this helps!!!